# ConTeXt: uppercase ß, customizing glyph substitution

Tags: context, context-mkiv, german

I've been trying to get a capital ß out of ConTeXt in contexts where automatic uppercasing is meant to happen, and get strange results. I am very new to ConTeXt. Also, I don't like the oldtsyle numerals with caps or smallcaps and need to automatically switch to some sort of lining figures.

Here's my testbed:

```
\mainlanguage[de]
\language[de]

\uccode`ß="1E9E    % This gives the capital ß to \uppercase

\definefontfeature[fcalluna][default][] % I tried all the font features built 
                                                % into Calluna, to no avail.

\definefontfamily [myfamily] [serif][Calluna][features=fcalluna]
\definefontfamily [myfamily] [sans] [Linux Biolinum O][features=fcalluna]
\definefontfamily [myfamily] [mono] [TeX Gyre Cursor]

\setupbodyfont [myfamily]
\startTEXpage[offset=10pt]
    \starttabulate[|l|l|l|]
         \NC \it Command \NC \it Calluna \NC \it Linux Biolinum \NC\NR
        \NC\type{\WORD{Gruß134}}:       \NC\WORD{Gruß134}           \NC {\ss\WORD{Gruß134}}         \NC\NR
        \NC\type{\uppercase{Gruß134}}:  \NC\uppercase{Gruß12134}    \NC{\ss\uppercase{Gruß134}}     \NC\NR
        \NC\type{\sc{Gruß134}}:             \NC{\sc Gruß134}            \NC{\ss{\sc Gruß134}}           \NC\NR
        \NC\type{\Cap{Gruß134}:}        \NC\Cap{Gruß134}            \NC{\ss \Cap{Gruß134}}      \NC\NR
        \NC\type{\cap{Gruß134}:}        \NC\cap{Gruß134}            \NC{\ss \cap{Gruß134}}      \NC\NR
        \NC\type{{\sc\lowercase{Gruß134}}:}         \NC{\sc\lowercase{Gruß134}}             \NC{\ss\sc\lowercase{Gruß134}}  \NC\NR
    \stoptabulate
\stopTEXpage
```

That gives me:

[image]

Well, I didn't expect to get the uppercase or small-caps ß "out of the box", but I had expected some consistency. `\WORD` just substitutes two S-glyphs instead of, e.g., the SS ligature or the capital ß. `\uppercase` is the one that's influenced by `\uccode`. `\sc` and `\Cap` both don't find Calluna's small-cap ß, which may be in a strange position in the font, but nevertheless exists.

Obviously, my aim is to see the uppercase and the small-caps ß when I let a header or something do something like `\uppercase` or `\sc`. I'd like to see the real small caps; not some scaled-down uppercase. And I'd like an automatic switch to lining figures.

Comment: I deleted my comments to avoid the distraction. If there is no reply here, you may consider posting this question on the context mailing list. I cannot help because I don't know how fonts work.

Comment: On the mailing list I was told that the problem in `\WORD` will be solved in the next beta. That's only a partial consolation, though. There are other issues like switching from oldstyle to numerals that go with uppercase or small caps. It seems it is really a general question of "How can I customize glyph substitution?".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to fix the font itself to have the correct mapping.  By default the `ß` in Calluna Regular has no substitutions for smallcaps.  You have to add the `smcp` substitution with `uni1E9E.smcp` as the target glyph (the `smcp` suffix is crucial, otherwise you obtain the uppercase version).

I edited the font with FontForge.

[image]

Afterwards your exact example typesets as

[image]

---

Alternatively, you can edit the font on the fly using the `fonts.handlers` approach in Lua.  I have asked the question [How to adjust font features in LuaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/312154) about it which is still lacking a canonical answer at the time of writing, but from the examples given one can sometimes construct working solutions.

```
\mainlanguage[de]
\language[de]

\startluacode
fonts.handlers.otf.addfeature {
    name = "smcp",
    type = "substitution",
    data = {
        ["germandbls"] = "uni1E9E.smcp",
    }
}
\stopluacode

\uccode`ß="1E9E    % This gives the capital ß to \uppercase

\definefontfamily [myfamily] [serif] [Calluna]          [features=default]
\definefontfamily [myfamily] [sans]  [Linux Biolinum O] [features=default]
\definefontfamily [myfamily] [mono]  [TeX Gyre Cursor]

\setupbodyfont [myfamily]

\startTEXpage[offset=10pt]
  \starttabulate[|l|l|l|]
    \NC \it Command \NC \it Calluna \NC \it Linux Biolinum \NC\NR
    \NC\type{\WORD{Gruß134}}:       \NC\WORD{Gruß134}           \NC {\ss\WORD{Gruß134}}         \NC\NR
    \NC\type{\uppercase{Gruß134}}:  \NC\uppercase{Gruß12134}    \NC{\ss\uppercase{Gruß134}}     \NC\NR
    \NC\type{\sc{Gruß134}}:             \NC{\sc Gruß134}            \NC{\ss{\sc Gruß134}}           \NC\NR
    \NC\type{\Cap{Gruß134}:}        \NC\Cap{Gruß134}            \NC{\ss \Cap{Gruß134}}      \NC\NR
    \NC\type{\cap{Gruß134}:}        \NC\cap{Gruß134}            \NC{\ss \cap{Gruß134}}      \NC\NR
    \NC\type{{\sc\lowercase{Gruß134}}:}         \NC{\sc\lowercase{Gruß134}}             \NC{\ss\sc\lowercase{Gruß134}}  \NC\NR
  \stoptabulate
\stopTEXpage
```

Output is the same as above.