# How to adjust font features in LuaTeX?

Tags: fonts, luatex, luaotfload

As of version 2.7 of `luaotfload` the support for font feature files (`.fea`) [has been dropped](https://github.com/lualatex/luaotfload/issues/347).

On the [ConTeXt mailing list](https://mailman.ntg.nl/pipermail/ntg-context/2016/083952.html) Hans showed how to make font substitution work through Lua.  More examples are available in the latest ConTeXt distribution ([001](http://minimals.metatex.org/current/context/test/doc/context/tests/mkiv/fonts/extensions-001.tex),
[002](http://minimals.metatex.org/current/context/test/doc/context/tests/mkiv/fonts/extensions-002.tex),
[003](http://minimals.metatex.org/current/context/test/doc/context/tests/mkiv/fonts/extensions-003.tex),
[004](http://minimals.metatex.org/current/context/test/doc/context/tests/mkiv/fonts/extensions-004.tex),
[005](http://minimals.metatex.org/current/context/test/doc/context/tests/mkiv/fonts/extensions-005.tex),
[006](http://minimals.metatex.org/current/context/test/doc/context/tests/mkiv/fonts/extensions-006.tex),
[007](http://minimals.metatex.org/current/context/test/doc/context/tests/mkiv/fonts/extensions-007.tex))

In the past I have been using font feature files to adjust the kerning of fonts on-the-fly.  From Hans' example it is not clear to me how to adjust kerning in the new syntax.  The below example does *not* work as intended.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\directlua{
fonts.handlers.otf.addfeature {
    name = "kern",
    {
        type = "pair",
        data = {
            [0x0041] = { [0x0056] = { false, { -200, 0, 0, 0 } } },
        }
    }
}
}
\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}
\begin{document}
AV
\end{document}
```

Can we have a comprehensive guide on how to adjust font features with LuaTeX with the `fonts.handlers` technique?

---

Related questions:

<sub>(These involve hooking into the `luaotfload.patch_font` callback)</sub>

- [Is there a way to adjust kerning for a specific character combination?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10455)
- [How to fix kerning of comma/colon after quotes?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52929)

Answer (score 66, accepted):

[Crimson](https://github.com/skosch/Crimson) is useful for experimenting with the new approach, because it’s free and defines few of the features it could support. Here are the features defined in its latest version:

```
       | r | i | b | bi | sb si |
|------+---+---+---+----+-------|
| c2sc | ✓ | ✓ | ✓ |    |       |
| kern | ✓ | ✓ | ✓ | ✓  | ✓     |
| liga |   |   |   | ✓  |       |
| onum | ✓ | ✓ |   | ✓  |       |
| ordn | ✓ |   |   |    |       |
| pnum | ✓ | ✓ |   | ✓  | ✓     |
| smcp | ✓ | ✓ | ✓ |    |       |
| zero | ✓ |   |   |    |       |
```

## Ligatures

It’s most surprising that `liga` is defined only in the bold italic face, so let’s fix that first.

Here’s Crimson before we add the feature:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Crimson}
\begin{document}
The five baffled officials flew off.

\textit{The five baffled officials flew off.}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of example]

Now here’s the fix:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\directlua{
fonts.handlers.otf.addfeature {
    name = "liga",
    {
        type = "ligature",
        data = {
            ['f_f'] = { "f", "f" },
            ['f_i'] = { "f", "i" },
            ['f_f_i'] = { "f", "f", "i" },
            ['f_l'] = { "f", "l" },
            ['f_f_l'] = { "f", "f", "l" },
            ['T_h'] = { "T", "h" },
        }
    },
    "some ligatures"
  }
}
\setmainfont{Crimson}
\begin{document}
The five baffled officials flew off.

\textit{The five baffled officials flew off.}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of second example]

In `['f_i'] = { "f", "i" }`, `['f_i']` is the glyph name of the ligature, and `{ "f", "i" }` are the letters to be ligatured. So if your font calls the ligature ‘fi’ rather than ‘f_i’, you should write `['fi'] = { "f", "i" }`. Also note that, in some fonts, `['f_f_b'] = { "f", "f", "b" }` doesn’t work, but `['f_f_b'] = { "ﬀ", "b" }` does.

As Ulrike Fischer explains in [tex.stackexchange.com/a/352864](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/352864) and in her answer to this question, if you have updated `luaotfload` recently (4 February 2017), you will need to revise the invocation of `\directlua` as follows:

```
\directlua{
  fonts.handlers.otf.addfeature{
    name = "liga",
    type = "ligature",
    data = {
      ['f_f'] = { "f", "f" },
      ['f_i'] = { "f", "i" },
      ['f_f_i'] = { "f", "f", "i" },
      ['f_l'] = { "f", "l" },
      ['f_f_l'] = { "f", "f", "l" },
      ['T_h'] = { "T", "h" },
    },
  }
}
```

## Stylistic and Contextual Alternates

Some alternates are desirable or not depending on what’s nearby.  For example, Crimson’s long-tailed ‘Q’ is attractive before ‘u,’ but looks silly or collides with other glyphs if it comes at the end of a word. Compare `salt`, which replaces a glyph by an alternate everywhere, and `calt`, which replaces it in some contexts only:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\directlua{
  fonts.handlers.otf.addfeature{
    name = "salt",
    type = "alternate",
    data =
    {
      Q = "Q.alt01",
    },
  }
  fonts.handlers.otf.addfeature{
    name = "calt",
    type = "chainsubstitution",
    lookups = {
      {
        type = "substitution",
        data = {
          ["Q"] = "Q.alt01",
        },
      },
    },
    data = {
      rules = {
        {
          after  = { { "u" } },
          current = { { "Q" } },
          lookups = { 1 },
        },
      },
    },
  }
}
\setmainfont{Crimson}
\begin{document}
(Questions about NASDAQ.) Meh.

{\addfontfeature{RawFeature=+salt}
  (Questions about NASDAQ.) Oops!}

{\addfontfeature{RawFeature=+calt}
  (Questions about NASDAQ.) That’s better.}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of example]

If Crimson had a long-tailed Q in its small caps, you’d get it by adding a line like this: `["q.sc"] = "q.scalt01",`.

## Superiors

Here I’ve found the principle, or part of it, but it’s probably better not applied to Crimson, because superiors 4–9 and 0 are designed to sit higher than superiors 1–3, as is especially noticeable in note 10 below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec,realscripts}
% see Ulrike’s answer at tex.stackexchange.com/a/235302/7883
\renewcommand\footnotemarkfont{\addfontfeature{RawFeature={+sups}}}
\renewcommand\fakesuperscript[1]{#1}
\usepackage[paperwidth=180pt,paperheight=150pt,margin=12pt]{geometry}
\directlua{
fonts.handlers.otf.addfeature {
    name = "sups",
    {
        type = "substitution",
        data = {
            one = "¹",
            ["one.onum"] = "¹",
            two = "²",
            ["two.onum"] = "²",
            three = "³",
            ["three.onum"] = "³",
            four = "⁴",
            ["four.onum"] = "⁴",
            five = "⁵",
            ["five.onum"] = "⁵",
            six = "⁶",
            ["six.onum"] = "⁶",
            seven = "⁷",
            ["seven.onum"] = "⁷",
            eight = "⁸",
            ["eight.onum"] = "⁸",
            nine = "⁹",
            ["nine.onum"] = "⁹",
            zero = "⁰",
            ["zero.onum"] = "⁰",
        }
    },
    "footnote figures"
  }
}
\setmainfont{Crimson}
\begin{document}
There\footnote{Note.} are\footnote{Note.} far\footnote{Note.}
too\footnote{Note.} many\footnote{Note.}  footnotes\footnote{Note.}
in\footnote{Note.} this\footnote{Note.}  little\footnote{Note.}
sentence.\footnote{Note.}
\end{document}
```

[image: sample of sups feature]

You’ll have to add more such lines (e.g., `["one.prop"] = "¹",` etc.,) if you want to have footnote figures whether you’re using the default figures, old-style figures, proportional figures, the slashed zero, or any other sort of figure provided.

For the `luaotfload` of February 2017, use `\directlua` this way:

```
\directlua{
  fonts.handlers.otf.addfeature{
    name = "sups",
    type = "substitution",
    data = {
      one = "¹",
      ["one.onum"] = "¹",
      two = "²",
      ["two.onum"] = "²",
      three = "³",
      ["three.onum"] = "³",
      four = "⁴",
      ["four.onum"] = "⁴",
      five = "⁵",
      ["five.onum"] = "⁵",
      six = "⁶",
      ["six.onum"] = "⁶",
      seven = "⁷",
      ["seven.onum"] = "⁷",
      eight = "⁸",
      ["eight.onum"] = "⁸",
      nine = "⁹",
      ["nine.onum"] = "⁹",
      zero = "⁰",
      ["zero.onum"] = "⁰",
    },
  }
}
```

## Remove a ligature

Crimson isn’t of much use to illustrate removal of ligatures, so here’s FPL Neu ([github.com/rstub/fplneu](https://github.com/rstub/fplneu)) without its ‘fk’ ligature:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\directlua{
fonts.handlers.otf.addfeature {
    name = "nofk",
    {
        type = "multiple",
        data = {
          ["f_k"] = { "f", "k" },
        }
    },
    "get rid of fk ligatures"
  }
}
\setmainfont{FPL Neu}
\begin{document}
Kafka

\addfontfeature{RawFeature=+nofk}
Kafka
\end{document}
```

[image: output of example]

The result is hardly visible in a font like Garamond Premier Pro, with its long-armed f, and I can’t seem to combine this `nofk` feature with extra kerning.

For the `luaotfload` of February 2017, use `\directlua` this way:

```
\directlua{
  fonts.handlers.otf.addfeature{
    name = "nofk",
    type = "multiple",
    data = {
      ["f_k"] = { "f", "k" },
    },
  }
}
```

## Select among standard ligatures

Some fonts put more in their `liga` feature than one could wish. For example, LTC Kaatskill Pro, a lovely Goudy design, makes œ a standard rather than a discretionary ligature, with the result that not only words like ‘œdema’ but even ‘does’ and ‘poem’ are affected.  Using `type = "multiple"`, as for ‘fk’ above, would fix ‘does’ but interfere with ‘œdema,’ so we need another approach.

To illustrate, let’s examine [a freely available Carolingian minuscule](https://www.xn--schffel-7wa.ch/kps_fonts/0850_carolina_tours.otf). With `liga`, it produces results one could use to ease students into a paleography course:

```
\documentclass[12pt,latin]{octavo}
\usepackage{babel,fontspec,microtype}
\setmainfont{0850 Carolina Tours}
\linespread{1.10345}
\begin{document}
Invocat te, Domine, fides mea quam dedisti mihi, quam inspirasti mihi
per humanitatem Filii tui, per ministerium praedicatoris tui.
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

For decorative rather than scholarly purposes, we’d want to remove whatever is defined in `liga` but unfamiliar to contemporary readers.

Besides the harmless ‘ff,’ ‘fi,’ ‘fl,’ ‘ft,’ and ‘ll,’ `liga` adds an ‘oe’ ligature and *e caudata* for ‘ae’; it also replaces ‘i’ and ‘j’ with their dotless versions, and substitutes ‘ſ’ for ‘s,’ ‘u’ for ‘v,’ and ‘V’ for ‘U.’ We can remove those ligatures and substitutions by turning off `liga`, and add back the harmless ligatures by defining them as `rlig`, a feature which is on by default:

```
\documentclass[12pt,latin]{octavo}
\usepackage{babel,fontspec,microtype}
\directlua{
  fonts.handlers.otf.addfeature{
    name = "rlig",
    type = "ligature",
    data = {
      ['f_f'] = { "f", "f" },
      ['fi'] = { "f", "i" },
      ['fl'] = { "f", "l" },
      ['f_t'] = { "f", "t" },
      ['l_l'] = { "l", "l" },
    },
  }
}
\setmainfont{0850 Carolina Tours}[
  Ligatures=NoCommon]
\linespread{1.10345}
\begin{document}
Invocat te, Domine, fides mea quam dedisti mihi, quam inspirasti mihi
per humanitatem Filii tui, per ministerium praedicatoris tui.
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

## Stubborn fonts

Sometimes one or more ligatures don’t work, and adding them as above doesn’t help. This happens when a font’s lookups define the ligatures in the wrong order, as [Khaled Hosny remarks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89963/how-to-suppress-a-rare-ligature-that-pre-empts-a-common-ligature-for-the-sam/421775#comment195614_89963). Fixing the problem without editing the font itself can be quite difficult if the lookups are especially complex, but often there’s no need to edit the font.

For example, [Goudy’s Newstyle](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/matteson-typographics/newstyle/) defines ‘fi’ and ‘fl’ in its `liga` feature, and slightly different ‘fi’ and ‘fl’ glyphs in its `dlig` feature. There are also glyphs for ‘ct,’ ‘fb,’ ‘ff,’ ‘ffi,’ ‘fj,’ ‘ffl,’ ‘fk,’ ‘st,’ and (in the italic) ‘Th,’ but no feature is defined to ease their use.  Adding the two-character ligatures to `liga` works, but adding the ‘ffi’ and ‘ffl’ ligatures doesn’t, apparently because the ‘fi’ and ‘fl’ ligatures are already in the lookup. But all is well if we turn off `liga` and define the ligatures we want as `rlig`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\directlua{
  fonts.handlers.otf.addfeature{
    name = "rlig",
    type = "ligature",
    data = {
      ['ffi'] = { "f", "f", "i" },
      ['ffl'] = { "f", "f", "l" },
      ['fb'] = { "f", "b" },
      ['ff'] = { "f", "f" },
      ['fh'] = { "f", "h" },
      ['fi'] = { "f", "i" },
      ['fj'] = { "f", "j" },
      ['fk'] = { "f", "k" },
      ['fl'] = { "f", "l" },
    },
  }
  fonts.handlers.otf.addfeature{
    name = "ilig",
    type = "ligature",
    data = {
      ['Th'] = { "T", "h" },
      ['Th.swsh'] = { "T.swsh", "h" },
    },
  }
}
\setmainfont{Newstyle}[
  Script=Default,
  Ligatures=NoCommon,
  Numbers=OldStyle,
  ItalicFeatures={RawFeature=+ilig}]
\begin{document}
The five baffled officials flew off.

\textit{The five baffled officials flew off.}

\textit{\addfontfeatures{Style=Swash}The five baffled officials flew off.}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

If a font’s `liga` feature contains many ligatures, it’s easier to keep `liga` on, break up only the problematic ligatures, and then restore them in `rlig`. For example, this produces the same output as above:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\directlua{
  fonts.handlers.otf.addfeature{
    name = "nolg",
    type = "multiple",
    data = {
      ['fi'] = { "f", "i" },
      ['fl'] = { "f", "l" },
    },
  }
  fonts.handlers.otf.addfeature{
    name = "rlig",
    type = "ligature",
    data = {
      ['ffi'] = { "f", "f", "i" },
      ['ffl'] = { "f", "f", "l" },
      ['fb'] = { "f", "b" },
      ['ff'] = { "f", "f" },
      ['fh'] = { "f", "h" },
      ['fi'] = { "f", "i" },
      ['fj'] = { "f", "j" },
      ['fk'] = { "f", "k" },
      ['fl'] = { "f", "l" },
    },
  }
  fonts.handlers.otf.addfeature{
    name = "ilig",
    type = "ligature",
    data = {
      ['Th'] = { "T", "h" },
      ['Th.swsh'] = { "T.swsh", "h" },
    },
  }
}
\setmainfont{Newstyle}[
  Script=Default,
  Numbers=OldStyle,
  ItalicFeatures={RawFeature=+ilig},
  RawFeature=+nolg]
\begin{document}
The five baffled officials flew off.

\textit{The five baffled officials flew off.}

\textit{\addfontfeatures{Style=Swash}The five baffled officials flew off.}
\end{document}
```

## CAVEAT

I don’t really understand what I’ve done, and there may be better ways (which I’d be glad to learn about), but at least things are more or less working.

## ADDENDUM

With some trepidation, I’ve created my first (and probably last) [GitHub repository](https://github.com/mewtant/fonts-in-luatex), where I’ll gradually put notes on fonts I’ve tried to fix. That should prevent this answer from becoming cluttered with discussions of typefaces to which few have access, save others with the same fonts from duplicating my labor, and perhaps allow for joint discovery of more satisfactory solutions.

Comment: This is really great, I wish I could upvote you more. Do you, by any chance, also know, how to deactivate a certain ligature? In German texts the ligature f_k is frowned upon, and I used to remove it via a liga feature `sub \f_k by \f \k;`

Comment: @FredFisch Before I work on this, have you tried `selnolig`?

Comment: Yes. The thing is that using `selnolig` I can't manually kern the pairs anymore which get broken up by the package. If there is no ligature, then the glyphs should not "touch" each other; unfortunately this is not possible with `selnolig`; see this question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/315123

Comment: @FredFisch I’ve added a way to remove ligatures, but your kerning problem remains.  I know little about German typography, but I get the best results for French texts with fonts made by French designers.  It’s an enormous job to adapt a font for use with a language to which the designer wasn’t sensitive.

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort! What is your ressource that you used to produce these examples?

Comment: @FredFisch I keep staring at `texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaotfload/luaotfload-features.lua`, especially lines 1305–1326 and 1816–1943, guess at its meaning, and spend time in trial-and-error.  I’d love to see documentation by someone who understands these things and isn’t just guessing.

Comment: It's possible to add another `fonts.handlers.otf.addfeature` into the same `\directlua` statement (named e.g. `ktest` of type `kern`, just like in Ulrikes answer, for the pair `f`, `k`), and to reference it like this: `\setmainfont[RawFeature={+nofk,+ktest}]{Linux Libertine O}` -- but the behaviour is very erratic! The inter-letter space changes on every compilation; very weird...  Documentation is clearly missing...

Comment: Excellent post! Can you provide an example using character classes such as @uppercase?

Comment: @meide Do you mean for producing something like a `calt` or `init` feature? I *wish* I knew how to do that. It would probably begin like `type = "chainsubstitution",` or `type = "chainposition",` but I don't know how it would continue.  I’ll experiment if I have time (maybe ten months from now…).

Comment: Yeah, I think. It's really hard to find documentation for how the addfeature stuff works....

Comment: Thank you continuously improving your answer.  Very useful!

Comment: Your answer doesn't address the mysterious `[0x0041] = { [0x0056] = { false, { -200, 0, 0, 0 } } },` syntax the question has. Is that sequence valid and if so, what does it do and how? I have problems setting up kerning in LuaLaTeX myself ...

Comment: @lblb Since the O.P. asked for a comprehensive guide, and since Ulrike Fischer had already written an answer about kerning, I decided to address other items that would go into a comprehensive guide.  There are certainly many more parts needed before this page is comprehensive, but no single answer has to be comprehensive.  Does Mrs. Fischer’s answer help with your question?  If not, she’s better placed to answer you than I am, since I haven’t done much experimentation with kerning yet.

Comment: @Thérèse I'm sorry to re-up the subject. But I have made some code with contextual ligatures that no longer works (and I don't know why, probably some more change in Lua). Something seems to be broken with 'lookups'. By any chance do you know why?

Comment: @R.Alexandre The example above still works for me; if you post your code somewhere, I’ll take a look.

Comment: @Thérèse That would be very nice of you, thank you. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/523572/ligature-font-feature-no-longer-works

Comment: The long-tailed Q didn't work for me, but the others did. I use Overleaf with TeX Live version 2019.

Comment: @Someone With Crimson or with some other font? Crimson has been revised since I wrote this answer, so some parts may need adjusting.

Comment: @Thérèse I used Crimson.

Comment: @Someone The above example of changing the tail of Q with `salt` and `calt` still works for me in Overleaf. Have you modified the example in any way?

Comment: No, I doubt so. I only used `calt`, not `salt`.

Comment: @Someone Hmmm. If you post a MWE somewhere, I may be able to figure it out.

Comment: Is there a difference between `alternate` and `substitution`?

Answer (score 31):

This here (an adaption of the example from the context list) works for me

### Edit on February 2017

The syntax seems to have changed. data and type are no longer in a subtable and the explaining text does harm. The new code working for me (in a current TeXLive 2016 and in MiKTeX) is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\directlua
{
 fonts.handlers.otf.addfeature 
  {
    name = "ktest",
    type = "kern",
    data = 
        {
            ["A"] = { ["V"] =  -200 },
        },
  }
 }
\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}[RawFeature=+ktest]
\setsansfont{Latin Modern Roman}

\begin{document}
  AV \sffamily AV
\end{document}
```

### Old version

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\directlua{
fonts.handlers.otf.addfeature {
    name = "ktest",
    {
        type = "kern",
        data = {
            ["A"] = { ["V"] =  -200 },
        }
    },
    "extra kerns"
}
}
\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}[RawFeature=+ktest]
\setsansfont{Latin Modern Roman}

\begin{document}
  AV \sffamily AV
\end{document}
```

[image]

But there are imho quite a number of open questions regarding the correct syntax (instead of `["A"]`   `A` alone seems to work too) and the values (what unit is -200)?  How should such extra features be named? Do they all need a name? How can packages implement such features and avoid clashes with other packages?

Comment: Thank you very much for solving the specific example from my question!  The actual question however is, whether we can have a review of what is possible and how it can be done with `fonts.handlers`.  The issue of the syntax not being final is minor, as an answer can always be updated later.

Comment: BTW: In the feature file syntax -200 would correspond to -200/1000em.

Comment: @HenriMenke: As you saw in the context list answer you can get quite fast working code from Hans to specific questions. What you seldom get it good documentation. It is even unclear if the interface is stable. So it is up to us to improve the situation. Imho we should try to extend this question and its answers to a definite "how to manipulate kernings" reference. And create more questions for other handlers.

Comment: I experimented a bit: The description string `"extra kerns"` seems to be optional (nothing happens when I leave it out).  When I use `name = "kern"`, the feature is automatically applied together with all other entries in the `kern` feature.  This seems more convenient than having to declare an extra feature.  So far, I haven't found out how to make vertical kerning work (a.k.a. positioning in the feature files), how to adjust kerning around a single character, and how to adjust kerning when the partner is a space (I can't choose `0x0020`, because space in TeX is handled differently).

Comment: I have [checked again](http://hastebin.com/hatelegume.tex) and the units of kerning are (as in the feature files) 1/1000em.

Comment: Just noticed something very strange: if I try to adjust the kerning of a second pair of letters by adding the line `["A"] = { ["W"] =  -200 },` after `["A"] = { ["V"] =  -200 },` the adjustment to the pair “AV” vanishes.

Comment: @Thérèse: You should add the W-setting to the existing  table for A. `["A"] = { ["V"] =  -200 ,  ["W"] =  -200 }`, (but curiously the 200 leads to a much larger kerning now.)

Comment: @HenriMenke Simple question from an ignorant: is there any way to use glyph names instead of unicode like [0x0041] as argument of data = {...} ?

Comment: @PaoloPolesana Yes, you can.  For a simple example see [this answer of mine](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/326110/10995) (it is a ConTeXt answer but the Lua part will stay the same for LaTeX).

Comment: @PaoloPolesana: My example use glyph names ("A"), so I don't understand the question.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Defining a ligature, I found that the string                                   ['Iacute'] = { "afii10026", "acutecmb"} does not apply. The glyph names are taken from the Adobe standard. After some trials I found that ['Iacute'] = { "И", 0x0301} works perfectly. So: some glyph names are accepted, while other not. Which is the standard?

Comment: @HenriMenke Thank you: anyway I'm still confused... I see a lot of way to call the characters it these examples: "A", [0x0041], 'f_i' for ligatures, also 'iacute' from Adobe glyph names, "Q.alt01", "uni1E9E.smcp"... This is for me a complete mess! I need some reference to order my knowledge...

Comment: @PaoloPolesana The problem is that the fonts are a mess here.  Naming is highly inconsistent.

Comment: @HenriMenke I also found that in some position of the string some names are consistent, while in other not: in defining a ligature ['Iacute'] = { "afii10026", "acutecmb"} does not apply. The glyph names are taken from the Adobe standard. After some trials I found that ['Iacute'] = { "И", 0x0301} works perfectly. Here I had to mix 'direct typing' (cyrillic И type) and this '0x0301' unicode standard... How to understand it? I didn't even know there was so many ways to call a type!!!

Comment: I agree, the syntax is a bit confusing, regarding to glyph  names. As to unit of "-200", I believe it is standard PS unit, that is 1 thousandth of em, and -200 is -20% type size

Comment: @Someone I approved the edit, but I would really prefer if you don't do such cosmetics edits which don't add anything useful to an four years old answer and cost only time to review.