# Kerning against space, which model is the most suitable one?

Tags: typography, kerning

Many professional fonts contain kerning instructions between the space (`U+0020`, the character) and other characters. These kerns help the pages achieve a more balanced *typographical colour*. For example, when an uppercase letter `T` follows a word space (i.e., `<space>T`), because of the extra hollow spot left to the vertical stem of the `T`, this word space would *appear* bigger/wider than other word spaces. So a font designer may want to reduce this kind of hollow spot by adding negative kern between the pair `<space>` and `T`.

But TeX doesn’t treat `<space>` as “character”. More precisely, a `(Category 10, Character 32)` token is converted into a glue node when typesetting, and such glue will have (1) normal width, (2) stretchability, and (3) shrinkability, coming from the current font. Therefore, it is *impossible* to auto-kern against space in classical TeX. In LuaTeX, however, something *can* be tried (see the post [Kerning against word space in LuaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/356828) by @YanZhou).

My question is *not* about “how does one implement kerning against space in certainTeX”, but rather “if one were to insert these kerns manually, then what these kerns should be in the TeX world”.

---

#### A toy example

Let’s say there is a font with `<space>` designed to be 210 units wide. Here, one unit equals 1⁄1000 em. Using normal convention of TeX, the stretchability will be 105 units, and the shrinkability will be 70 units. Suppose the lowercase letter `f` has a large overhanging terminal, so that the combination `f<space>` is supposed to have a *positive* kern of 30 units in between, according to the font. Also, `<space>T` is supposed to have a *negative* kern of 30 units in between. Now, consider the following snippet from a text paragraph:

```
...f H T...
```

TeX will convert this into a linked list:

```
...
<char: f>
<glue: 210 plus 105 minus 70>
<char: H>
<glue: 210 plus 105 minus 70>
<char: T>
...
```

How should we treat the positive/negative 30-unit kerns?

#### Model 1

Insert these kerns as *explicit kerns* (via the `\kern` primitive):

```
<char: f>
<kern: +30>
<glue: 210 plus 105 minus 70>
<char: H>
<glue: 210 plus 105 minus 70>
<kern: -30>
<char: T>
```

#### Model 2

Insert these kerns as *glues* (via the `\hskip` primitive), but with neither stretchability nor shrinkability:

```
<char: f>
<glue: +30>
<glue: 210 plus 105 minus 70>
<char: H>
<glue: 210 plus 105 minus 70>
<glue: -30>
<char: T>
```

#### Model 3

Insert these kerns as *glues* (via the `\hskip` primitive), but with both stretchability and shrinkability. Reason: Since the space following `f` is supposed to be 210+30=240 units wide, it should have 120-unit stretchability (15 units more) and 80-unit shrinkability (10 units more).

```
<char: f>
<glue: +30 plus +15 minus +10>
<glue: 210 plus 105 minus 70>
<char: H>
<glue: 210 plus 105 minus 70>
<glue: -30 plus -15 minus -10>
<char: T>
```

---

Models 2 and 3 seem more superior than Model 1 when it comes to line-breaking, but I don’t know for sure. I can’t decide between Model 2 and Model 3 either, and maybe there is another alternative. Discussions welcome!

Answer (score 1):

If I recall correctly, there is a word boundary that's part of the TeX metric model that can be kerned against (it's also used for ligatures to allow for beginning/end-of-word variant characters like in, e.g., Arabic). I would expect that a decent TeX implementation would take kerns against spaces and treat them as kerns against word boundaries which would allow them to be used even in Knuth's unmodified TeX program.