# Kerning with selnolig

Tags: luatex, kerning, selnolig

You can use the `selnolig` package to break up inappropriate ligatures
automatically.  For example, 'leaflet' should arguably not have an fl-ligature,
and this can be prevented with `\nolig{leaflet}{leaf|let}`.  But with many
fonts, breaking this ligature (with `selnolig`) still does not prevent the `f` from
touching the `l`.  I even tried kerning the `fl` pair with fontforge, but it seems
that `selnolig` does not use the font's kerning.  The following will
print 'leaflet' in increasing levels of appropriateness (I think; is it not a rule of typography that letters that do not form ligatures should not touch?).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{selnolig}

\setmainfont{ebgaramond}

\begin{document}
leaflet

\nolig{leaflet}{leaf|let}
leaflet

leaf\kern1.3333ptlet
\end{document}
```

[image]

How could I get the last result without the explicit kern?

PS.  This way of breaking the `fl`-ligature can be seen in Nietzsche, Werke in drei Baenden, Carl Hanser Verlag, 1977:

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64953/discussion-on-question-by-toothrot-kerning-with-selnolig).

Comment: The screenshot, to me, is a vivid reminder of how bad typography could be in the 19 century. I see inconsistent irregular interword spacing and poor kerning galore... Oh, and I see way too much whitespace between "f" and "l" in "Verzweiflung"...

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "it seems that `selnolig` does not use the font's kerning". (I'm afraid I have no idea what this is supposed to mean.)

Comment: @Mico, I meant that changing the font's kerning of fl so that they would not touch had no effect.

Comment: @Toothrot - `selnolig`'s `\nolig` macro works by inserting a so-called "whatsit" (not my term!) between the `f` and `l` characters. This prevents ligation -- which, after all, is the whole reason for doing this. A side-effect is that because the `f` and `l` characters are no longer directly adjacent, the kerning algorithm cannot kick in and insert a custom kern. (If the whatsit were removed in order to allow kerning, the `fl` ligature would show up once again. Gah!)

Comment: @Mico, I see.  Anyway, I think you are right about the short f approach.  Maybe one just has to learn some vector editing if one wants to use something other than ebgaramond.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not familiar with the term "vector editing".

Comment: @Mico, font editing.

Comment: @Toothrot - Now I get it. :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't think you would ever do this in English but in other languages with a fondness for compound words it is more of an issue.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\directlua{
function breaklig (s)
return 
string.gsub(
string.gsub(
s,
'leaflet','leaf\string\\kern.5em let'),
'shelfful','shelf\string\\kern.5em ful')
end
luatexbase.add_to_callback('process_input_buffer',breaklig,'break ligatures in specified words')
}
\begin{document}


I once wrote a leaflet that (or was it a pamphlet) that had a flipped flyleaf.
Actually I have a shelfful of them.

\end{document}
```

Comment: What if I have a macro `\leaflet` or `\begin{leaflet}` to typeset leaflets containing the word »leaflet«?

Comment: @HenriMenke either don't do that:-) or work harder on the replacement patterns for example you could make the pattern check that the character before the first letter in the word was not `\ ` or `{` or (simpler) first to a replacement changing `\leaflet` to `ZZZ` then add the kerns then change ZZZ back to \leaflet.  None of that is hard just tedious

Comment: @HenriMenke also of course here I have enabled the callback globally in the preamble, you might instead just define the function globally but enable and disable the callback locally in some specific environments that you know just contain text

Comment: I'd use `pre_linebreak_filter` and walk all the nodes until I find the sequence `leaftlet` then back up and insert the kern.  That does not break macro parsing.

Comment: @HenriMenke yep as I said in a comment somewhere below the question traversing the nodes is another possibility, probably better but I didn't have a lot of time and the OP said not familiar with Lua and doing it this way is certainly simpler and easier to customise. if in principle not as robust.

Comment: (+1) for 'I don't think you would ever do this in English' ....

Comment: @HenriMenke - Rather than insert a kern directly (between the "f" and the "l"), it would be better to insert  a discretionary, with a kern in the discretionary's third argument. That way, the line-breaking algorithm could still operate on the word "leaflet".

Answer (score 14):

A major, and frankly vexing, practical issue when breaking up typographically inappropriate `fl` and `ffl` ligatures is how much whitespace (if any) should be inserted between `f` (or `ff`) and `l`. This issue doesn't come up when breaking up `ff` ligatures (cf "shelfful" and the screenshot below), and it's generally a less-vexing issue when breaking up `fi` (e.g., "aufisst" in German) and `ffi` (e.g., "Stoffisolierung") ligatures.

The "right" amount of whitespace that should be inserted between `f` (or `ff`) and `l` happens to depend crucially on the exact shapes of the `f` and `ff` glyphs. For some fonts, such as Palatino, Aldus, and Dante, no extra whitespace is needed at all, as these fonts' `f` and `ff` glyphs have fairly short "arms" which don't collide with the `l` glyph even if no whitespace is inserted. (Aside: this is probably a deliberate design feature of these fonts.) The `babel` package's `"|` method is programmed to insert `0.03em` of whitespace. While this amount is OK for Computer Modern and Latin Modern, it is actually way too much for Palatino on the one hand and not enough for fonts such as EB Garamond, Caslon, Sabon, and Linux Liberine O on the other. For EB Garamond, for instance, it looks like `0.1em` -- or more than three times the amount inserted with `babel`'s `"|` method -- is the amount of whitespace that must be inserted if the `f` and `l` glyphs absolutely, positively must not touch each other. In my opinion, the typeset word "Verzweiflung" looks just awful if 0.1em of whitespace is inserted: One problem -- the inappropriate `fl` ligature -- has been replaced with a problem -- the unsightly gap inside the word -- that's nearly as bad! (Another aside: Maybe the "typographic rule" you mention, that adjacent non-ligated glyphs must not touch, has to be reconsidered.)

The real solution when breaking up `fl` and `ffl` ligatures, then, is to use variants of the glyphs `f` and `ff` that have "short" arms, i.e., arms that don't protrude (much) to the right and hence don't collide with a "tall" glyph such as `l`. Unfortunately, very few fonts currently offer such short-armed glyphs. I'm aware of only EB Garamond and Linux Libertine as font families that provide them. (Tediously, the "slots" where EB Garamond and Linux Libertine store their short-armed f-variants aren't the same. This makes programming up an automated use of the short-armed glyphs rather tedious and error-prone. This is also why I haven't gotten around to implement the short-f approach in the `selnolig` package...)

Another solution, which may or may not be available to you, is to use a font such as Palatino whose `f` and `ff` glyphs have short arms and thus don't collide with trailing `l` glyphs.

---

The following table compares the outputs of various methods for breaking up `fl` ligatures. 
Note that the "new" method used below is similar to the one David Carlisle used in his answer, except that it uses a so-called "discretionary" to continue to allow line breaks (with hyphens) to occur in the word "Verzweiflung". Note also that no whitespace has to be inserted between the 2 `f` glyphs in `shelfful`, for any of the fonts considered here.

[image]

```
\documentclass[english,ngerman]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec,babel,selnolig,booktabs,array,geometry}
\providecommand\xx{}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\xx}l}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\xx}r}
\setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}

\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode}
function breaklig (s)
    s = s:gsub ( 'Verzweiflung' ,
        'Ver\\-zweif\\discretionary{-}{}{\\kern0.10em}lung' )
    return s
end
luatexbase.add_to_callback( 'process_input_buffer' ,
    breaklig , 'break ligatures in specified words' )
\end{luacode}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{@{}lRLLLLLL@{}} 
&&    \multicolumn{2}{c}{\ttfamily selnolig}  &
      \multicolumn{1}{c}{\ttfamily babel "|}     &
      \multicolumn{1}{c}{\ttfamily "new"\ meth.} &
      \multicolumn{1}{c@{}}{\ttfamily f.short}\\
&&   \multicolumn{2}{c}{\ttfamily ("whatsit")} &
     \multicolumn{1}{c}{\ttfamily (0.03em)}  &
     \multicolumn{1}{c}{\ttfamily (0.10em)}  &
     \multicolumn{1}{c@{}}{(if available)} \\

\cmidrule(lr){3-4} \cmidrule(lr){5-5} \cmidrule(lr){6-6} \cmidrule(l){7-7}

% start with default font (Latin Modern)
\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}
Latin Modern
&ff fl & shelfful & {V}erzweiflung & Verzweif"|lung & Verzweiflung \\

\gdef\xx{\setmainfont{EB Garamond}[Scale=MatchLowercase]}
\xx EB Garamond
&ff fl & shelfful & {V}erzweiflung & Verzweif"|lung & Verzweiflung & 
Verzwei\symbol{983911}lung\\

\gdef\xx{\setmainfont{Adobe Caslon Pro}[Scale=MatchLowercase]}
\xx Caslon
&ff fl & shelfful & {V}erzweiflung & Verzweif"|lung & Verzweiflung \\

\gdef\xx{\setmainfont{Sabon Next LT Pro}[Scale=MatchLowercase]}
\xx Sabon
&ff fl & shelfful & {V}erzweiflung & Verzweif"|lung & Verzweiflung \\

\gdef\xx{\setmainfont{Palatino Linotype}[Scale=MatchLowercase]}
\xx Palatino
&ff fl & shelfful & {V}erzweiflung & Verzweif"|lung & Verzweiflung \\

\gdef\xx{\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}[Scale=MatchLowercase]}
\xx Linux Lib.\ O
&ff fl & shelfful & {V}erzweiflung & Verzweif"|lung & Verzweiflung &
Verzwei\symbol{57568}\-lung\\
\end{tabular}

\bigskip
\setmainfont{EB Garamond}
Another comparison of the methods' outputs (EB Garmond only):

\begin{tabular}{@{}llll@{}}
\uselig{höflich} & \uselig{trefflich} & \uselig{aufisst} & bad!\\
höflich & trefflich & aufisst & selnolig \\
höf"|lich & treff"|lich & auf"|isst & babel \verb+"|+ \\
höf\discretionary{-}{}{\kern0.10em}lich 
& treff\discretionary{-}{}{\kern0.10em}lich 
& auf\discretionary{-}{}{\kern0.10em}isst
&  ``new'' method --- not good either \\
hö\symbol{983911}\-lich 
& tre\symbol{983904}\-lich 
& au\symbol{983911}\-isst
&  f.short \& f\_f.short --- best!
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why not `'Ver"-zweif"-\\kern.1em lung'`? (In function breaklig.)

Comment: @keth-tex - I'm not sure I understand your question. The Lua function is supposed to "work" whether or not `babel` is loaded with the `ngerman` option.

Comment: I wasn't aware that macros are defined differently across languages. (I just read the "Hyphenation and line breaking" section of the `babel` documentation for the first time.) Do I understand correctly that `'Ver"-zweif"-\\kern.1em lung'` works with `german` and `ngerman` (and some other) options and that `'Ver\\babelhyphen{soft}zweif\\babelhyphen{soft}\\kern.1em lung'` would also work as a general solution?

Comment: (At least for `babel` users?)

Comment: The `"-` shorthand is defined for `babel` users if `ngerman`, `german`, or a short list of other languages is chosen.

Comment: I am sorry to resurrect an ancient thread by commenting but as the relevant discussions are already here – without a real solution – I think it fits best. I really think the font’s kerning should ideally be honored to achieve a pleasing result.

Comment: (cont.) I wanted to suggest another approach: When I split unwanted ligatures by manually identifying them I don’t use babel’s `"|` but switch off ligatures via OT-features using `fontspec`, e.g. `\NL{Auflage}` with `\newcommand{\NL}[1]{{\addfontfeature{Ligatures=NoCommon}#1}}`. This retains the original kerning. Would it perhaps be possible to use this mechanism with `selnolig`?

Comment: @Florian - Many thanks for getting in touch and for making an interesting proposal. One issue I foresee with the `\NL` approach is that its scope may sometimes be too broad. E.g., for words such as `auffinden` and `aufflackern`, `\NL` will suppress not only the objectionable f-f ligature but also the unobjectionable `f-i` and `f-l` ligatures, respectively. For sure, readers will (and should!) raise their proverbial eyebrows if they come across both `finden` with an `f-i` ligature and `auffinden` without this ligature.

Comment: Very glad to find open ears! Yes, I've come across these, too, and haven't found a good fits-all solution but went for a compromise like `Stoff\NL{igel}` or `\NL{auf}\-finden`. Perhaps it is possible to establish rules where to put the scope of the font feature when there is more than one pair in the word, but I haven't tried yet. Personally I'd be more than content with `selnolig` taking care of the unproblematic ones and flagging the problematic ones for possible user-intervention. In a normal text there shouldn't be too many.

Comment: Another approach might be a user-interface for different whatsits so I could take the values from my font-file or determine my own ones: `whatsit-fl=.1em, whatsit-fi=.05em,...`

Comment: @Florian - An issue I encountered when I designed the overall "Gestalt" of `selnolig` is that many fonts actually do not provide good kerning values for `f-f`, `f-i` and `f-l`; my guess is that the font designers simply assumed that those combinations would never occur in practice as the `ff`, `fi`, and `fl` ligatures would replace the character pairs anyway. Hence, for quite a few fonts, `\NL{Auflage}` won't really "work" since the font's `f-l` entry in the kerning table wasn't chosen carefully. The multi-whatsit approach could be reasonably straightforward to implement; I'll have to check.

Comment: Working mostly with two fonts I hadn't thought about that many other fonts wouldn't have good kerning for these pairs... But it sort of makes sense as very few German and hardly any English publications bother to separate ligatures. On the other hand it's strange when you think of that it is only recently that automatic OT-ligatures have been widely available and many fonts are a lot older than that -- so the non-ligated pairs must have been standard.

Comment: Thinking about it, multi-whatsit might even be the better approach as it would allow people like me to set the values high enough to avoid ascender-collisions while other users might want to accept collisions for the sake of smaller spaces as discussed above. Would you know whether it is possible for luatex to extract the kern-tables (for what they are worth) from a given font so they could be used as defaults for the whatsits?

Comment: just wondering whether you might have had the time to have a look at multiple whatsits...? (would be great for my current project)

Comment: @Florian - Thanks for getting in touch. I'm very sorry to have to report that I haven't worked on the `selnolig` package since we corresponded about 10 months ago.