# Set global non-ligature kerning with selnolig

Tags: luatex, kerning, lua, selnolig

Similar to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/389302/kerning-with-selnolig) question I want to use `selnolig` but I don't like the fact that in words containing `fl` without ligature these two letters are too close together.

Like in [Mico's](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/389439/167001) answer I want to use the "new" method because I found that with the font I'm using this will make perfect kerning. Unfortunately the code given in this answer provides the "new" method only for single words.

Is it possible to use this method for every word with a non-ligature `fl` combination? In other words: Is it possible to add a fixed kerning between all `f` and `l` letters that are automatically broken into single letters by `selnolig`?

Here is a minimal example (taken from Mico's answer linked above):

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{selnolig}

\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode}
function breaklig (s)
    s = s:gsub ( 'Verzweiflung' ,
        'Ver\\-zweif\\discretionary{-}{}{\\kern0.05em}lung' )
    return s
end
luatexbase.add_to_callback( 'process_input_buffer' ,
    breaklig , 'break ligatures in specified words' )
\end{luacode}

\begin{document}

Verzwei\uselig{fl}ung {V}erzweiflung Verzweiflung

\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

- The first example uses a ligature that should not be used in this case.
- The second is the output produced by `selnolig` with the letters `f` and `l` too close together.
- The third uses the luacode above to create a `0.05em` kerning that does not interfere with TeX's hyphening algorithms (as far as I know).

I want to use the third one for all words containing `fl` where `selnolig` breaks the ligature.

Comment: Maybe you are interested in one of today's talks: https://tug.org/tug2018/program.html They will be broadcast via live stream https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0afEOEX-rEM

Comment: It would be easier to understand what you wanted if you added [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) to show what you are doing: without code that exhibits your problem we have to guess what you are doing, which makes it much harder to help.

Comment: Not possible.  `selnolig` breaks ligatures by inserting whatsits which completely disables kerning.  You could modify `selnolig` to insert tagged whatsits and then have the `linebreak_filter` callback walk the hlist and reinsert kerning on tagged nodes.

Comment: The short answer to your questions is, unfortunately, "no". When breaking up a ligature -- whether by inserting a "whatsit" during the `ligaturing` callback phase (`selnolig`'s current method) or by inserting an explicit amount of whitespace (David's method, or also the `babel`-shorthand method) -- it's also important to decide what to do regarding line-breaking possibilities. `selnolig`'s approach was chosen, in part, so as not to interfere with TeX's hyphenation algorithms. Note that David's answer (in the link you provided) potentially runs into trouble in this regard.

Comment: Actually I didn't link David's answer but your's. In your answer you used `discretionary` to not interfere with the hyphenation algorithms. So my questions is if one could expand your code to work with every word that uses `fl` with no ligature.