# Upright quote in DejaVu Serif

Tags: luatex, punctuation

I have this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}
\setmainfont{DejaVu Serif}
"Heading"
\end{document}
```

(run with LuaLaTeX, texlive2105) which gives this result:

[image: heading with italic quotes]

But I'd like to have upright quotes. The font contains the upright quotes (glyph id 5), so it should be technically possible.

Comment: You mean ‘typewriter quotes’?

Comment: @Bernard yes, the ones that look like an equal sign rotated 90 degrees.

Comment: @topskip `\rotatebox{90}{=}` ;-)

Comment: @topskip I image this to be quite hard, because in recent LuaTeX/luaotfload the syntax for font adjustments changed heavily and the usage of feature files has been abolished.  If you find out how to replace single glyphs, I'd be happy if you write an answer in [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/312154) of mine.

Comment: I have absolutely no such problem, except with `latin Modern`.

Comment: Copy ``Heading". See if that works

Comment: Obligatory [rant](https://randomdeterminism.wordpress.com/2009/05/15/quote-backtick-and-unicode-engine/)

Comment: @user170039 do you mean me? ``Heading" does not get me a very different result than "Heading". Different kind of quotation marks though, but still incorrect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to disable the automatic `Ligatures=TeX` feature:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\defaultfontfeatures[\rmfamily]{}
\setmainfont{DejaVu Serif}

\begin{document}

"Heading"

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This also disables `--` and `---` (and perhaps others I'm not aware of).

Comment: @HenriMenke Yes, of course. If one wants only *some* TeX standard ligatures, a new map file is needed.

Comment: I knew about the TeX ligatures, but I did not know that they were activated by default and how to disable them. This ansers my question (including the -- and --- ligatures). Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

With the new `luaotfload` syntax for the definition of extra font features (from v2.7 on, I guess).  Basically, we condone ligaturing the `"` to `”`, but then have a font feature which substitutes `”` back to `"`.  It might also be possible to hook into the ligaturing callback to prevent this particular ligature.

*Disclaimer:* I have no idea what I'm doing.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\directlua{
fonts.handlers.otf.addfeature {
    name = "altquot",
    {
        type = "substitution",
        data = {
            ["”"] = "\string\"",
        }
    }
}
}
\begin{document}
\setmainfont[RawFeature=+altquot]{DejaVu Serif}
"Heading" -- ---
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This also disables `\enquote{fobar}` (package `csquotes`).

Comment: @topskip Well, it simply substitutes *all* occurences of `”` to `"`, no matter where they come from.  It is not a question of input, but a question of output.  The substitution is applied on typesetting, i.e., everything that typesets as `”` will be converted to `"`.

Answer (score 3):

@topskip: Start using ConTeXt again! Other TeX ligatures (`--` and `---`) are enabled by default, quotes are not!

```
\setupbodyfont[dejavu]
\starttext
"Heading"
\stoptext
```

[image]

Comment: I like ConTeXt and this project would benefit from using ConTeXt. But I am not the only one involved in it, I won't be able to persuade others to participate...