# Remove specific ligature from specific font with LuaLaTeX

Tags: fonts, luatex, ligatures

I was recently gifted the Zapfino otf character, and I'm using it to typeset an "handwritten" letter inside of a book. I like the way the discretionary ligature are typeset, but the *Co* ligature is kind of a pain since the o is placed inside the C, which is not suitable for my composition.

Since this is confined in an environment inside of the book, I'd like to know whether it is possible to disable the ligature

- per font
- per environment

I'm using LuaLaTeX with TeX Live 2016.

**EDIT**
this has been closed by comments.

That is:

- one can use the Lua-specific features described in [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/315635/7883)
- One can resort to use the `selnolig` package, removing the ligature throughout the document via `\nolig{Co}{C|o}`. While this is more invasive and not font-based, it's quicker for some strange ligature such as mine.

I found that both solutions were adequate.

Comment: Have you tried loading the `selnolig` package and issuing the instruction `\nolig{Co}{C|o}`?

Comment: Since you didn’t provide a MWE to elaborate on, I suggest having a look at the eighth section of the manual of the `microtype` package.  As far as I know, ligatures can only be disabled globally.  Since you are using LuaLaTeX, there is also the `selnolig` package available, but I don’t think it exactly addresses your problem.  **Edit:** @Mico: Because the disablement is not context-based, in this case.

Comment: Well, I knew about `selnolig` but I did not know that ligatures cannot be disabled locally. I will look into the resources you suggested. Thanks

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti - Indeed, the main purpose of `selnolig` is to perform selective, context-based ligature suppression. However, the package's `\nolig` macro can also be used to suppress selected ligatures *globally*.

Comment: @ilFuria - I think there's an excellent chance that Zapfino will be the *only* font in your document that features a ligature for "Co". :-)

Comment: @Mico: Thanks for having pointed that out (it was rather obvious, after all—my mistake!).

Comment: Let me clarify: (1) I was speaking about pdfTeX and its `\tagcode` primitive.  (2) That primitive does not permit to disable ligatures only inside a group, but (3) it *does* permit disablement on a per-font basis.

Comment: Ok, now I'm quite confused. I understand there are two ways to achieve this. I know that that's probably the only font with a "co" ligature, but I was interested to the general case. I don't know which is best if `tagcode` or the `selnolig` package. Can you please elaborate in a more complete answer? Thanks

Comment: I don't have the font on my system, so I can't provide an answer with real code. :-(

Comment: @Mico: I don't like it per se, since I'm disabling a ligature globally via `selnolig`, and also I think I'm abusing the package since, as I understand it, it was created with another purpose in mind. Nevertheless for this special case I think it works, so thanks!

Comment: @ilFuria - Good to know that `selnolig` is working for you. :-) Don't worry one bit about possibly abusing the package because you're using it to suppress a ligature globally rather than for certain contexts only. Indeed, the package itself suppresses ligatures such as `fb`, `fh` and `fk` globally if either the `ngerman` or `english` language options were set. Incidentally, I can see no downside to suppressing the `Co` ligature globally rather than just for `Zapfino`: If this ligature is not desirable with `Zapfino`, it's probably not desirable with other fonts either, right?

Comment: @Mico yes indeed. I said "abusing" just because that the ligature-suppressing feature seemed more "composite word"-oriented and hyphenation-oriented. But with "Co" I think you're right!

Comment: I don’t have Zapfino, but see the “Remove a ligature” section of https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/315635/7883

Comment: @Thérèse fantastic! As soon as I will be able to test it, I'll try, and it seems just what I was searching for!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it is solved in the comments, as OP has stated in his edit of the question.

Comment: @Mico -- please add a simple answer, just for the record.  (for my motivation, see [What is the etiquette for providing an answer already in the comments?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7248/579).)

Comment: @barbarabeeton - Thanks for this suggestion. Unfortunately, a few minutes after you posted your comment the posting got closed for the reason "This question does not fall within the scope of TeX, LaTeX or related typesetting systems as defined in the help center." Answers may no longer be posted. :-(

Comment: @Moriambar -- as this question has been closed, and at some point in the future, comments may disappear, please add to your edit the information about the fix that worked.  it's a useful piece of information that someone else may be looking for.  (i'm following up according to suggestions made in this meta question: ,[What is the etiquette for providing an answer already in the comments?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7248/579). )

Comment: @barbarabeeton complied.

Comment: @Moriambar -- thanks.  very nicely done.