# fontspec: Small Caps feature wrong ligatures when using Renderer=Basic

Tags: luatex, fontspec, small-caps, ligatures

If I use `SmallCapsFeatures={Renderer=Basic}` as an option when setting the main font of the document, I get an obviously wrong ligature in the small caps shape. In the MWE the letters `T` and `h` are not typeset as separate glyphs in small caps but as a `Th`-ligature in regular upright shape. This is the case also with other ligature combinations, such as `fl`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[SmallCapsFeatures={Renderer=Basic}]{Linux Libertine O}
\begin{document}
\textsc{Thomson} \textsc{T\/homson}
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE of wrong small caps]

Removing `SmallCapsFeatures={Renderer=Basic}` makes the problem go away.  But I need this option in order to make use of the tracking feature of the `microtype` package.

How to circumvent this behaviour? Am I doing something wrong?

---

EDIT: Using the following makes the mentioned problem go away:

```
\setmainfont[SmallCapsFeatures={Renderer=Basic,Ligatures={NoCommon}}]{Linux Libertine O}
```

However, I wonder what I might be missing by this workaround...

Comment: If I use xelatex rather than lualatex (TeX Live 2016) there is no preoblem.

Comment: @HerbSchulz, thanks for narrowing it down, but I can't use XeLaTeX.

Comment: According to the change log in §30 of the `microtype` documentation, `Renderer=Basic` is no longer required.

Comment: @Thérèse that's great news, thank you. Unfortunately I'm stuck with TeX Live 2014 for this project, as the support for custom Feature Files with fontspec has been removed.
But now I see that you figured out how to do most of the stuff I need the new way: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/315635/46683 -- so maybe I can switch to Tex Live 2016...