# How to use fonts.handlers.otf.addfeature, etc.?

Tags: fonts, luatex, context, opentype

The following commands are used in some of the examples about Lua(La)TeX and ConTeXt in their
manuals, tutorials and on the net:

`fonts.handlers.otf.addfeature`, `fonts.protrusions.vectors`, `fonts.expansions.classes`, etc.

Is there any documentation on how to use these functions?

Any help would be gratefully appreciated.

Comment: For the first, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/312154

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Comment: [Hans' new font manual](http://pragma-ade.com/general/manuals/fonts-mkiv.pdf) has some info.

Comment: It seems like there is no manual other than Hans' new font manual.