# `ccmp` in Lua（la)TeX/ConTeXt, with Source Han serif font

Tags: luatex, context, opentype

Google and Adobe released a new CJK font [Source Han Serif](https://source.typekit.com/source-han-serif/?scid=social71226596) recently. One of the amazing feature is that, using opentype `ccmp` feature, it becomes possible to type the chinese character `biang`, as described in [this](https://blogs.adobe.com/CCJKType/2017/04/designing-implementing-biang.html) article. This character can be described using IDS as

```
⿺辶⿳穴⿰月⿰⿲⿱幺长⿱言马⿱幺长刂心
```

I saw that LuaTeX seems to support the ccmp feature. I am wondering how can I type this character.

This question is for my curiosity and just for fun.

[image]

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/312154/how-to-adjust-font-features-in-luatex

Comment: [here](https://blogs.adobe.com/CCJKType/2014/03/ids-opentype.html) are some clues. It seems a character substitution routine has to be constructed based in the values shown in that page.

Comment: @ElAndi, I've managed that, in both LuaLaTeX and ConTeXt. BTW, there is an extra space between the first two characters.

Comment: @naturalstupidity, I can't get pass typesetting the string of characters, but it won't compose characters. I don't know how yet... I don't understand how to typeset the Adobe example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think the release version of this font contains this feature yet; I was only able to get it to work with a different font:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}% only to conditionally load luaotfload if necessary
\begin{document}
\font\1="[Biang-Heavy.otf]" at 20pt\1
⿺辶⿳穴⿰月⿰⿲⿱幺長⿱言馬⿱幺長刂心
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes. I re-download a new version of the font. Then everything works perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Because the question is tagged [context](/questions/tagged/context) here a version of Will's solution for ConTeXt MKIV.  [Direct download of Biang Heavy](http://blogs.adobe.com/CCJKType/files/2014/03/Biang-Heavy.otf).

```
\definefontfeature[default][default][ccmp=yes]
\definefont[Biang][Biang-Heavy.otf*default at 20pt]
\starttext
\Biang ⿺辶⿳穴⿰月⿰⿲⿱幺長⿱言馬⿱幺長刂心
\stoptext
```

[image]

Comment: I missed that sorry. It had also been reported in the fontspec issue tracker so I assumed a LaTeX solution.

Answer (score 3):

[Source Han Serif](https://github.com/adobe-fonts/source-han-serif) and [Source Han Sans](https://github.com/adobe-fonts/source-han-sans)(v2.000) supports this feature (I use XeLaTeX here):

```
% XeLaTeX
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\def\biangT{⿺辶⿳穴⿰月⿰⿲⿱幺長⿱言馬⿱幺長刂心}
\def\biangS{⿺辶⿳穴⿰月⿰⿲⿱幺长⿱言马⿱幺长刂心}
\begin{document}
  \fontspec{Source Han Serif SC}%
  \biangT\biangS
  \fontspec{Source Han Sans SC}%
  \biangT\biangS
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1, but please use `article` for MWEs.  The `minimal` class was made for the test suite of LaTeX2e and has nothing to do with minimal working examples.

Comment: I want to get "⿰土畿（Ky-fan 樊土畿）" through your method, I failed, and I can't find the reason, can you tell me why?

Comment: @poorich `biang` is specially designed as it can be used via `ccmp` of the sequence. Source Han doesn't support transforming arbitrary sequence to a single glyph. Actually, a font must have the glyph, then you can use it.So at present, this character is not available, at least in Source Han Serif/Sans.

Comment: By the way, if you really need this glyph, please try [BabelStone Han PUA](http://www.babelstone.co.uk/Fonts/PUA.html). This character is at `U+F2E6`.