# insert the Chinese character 'Biáng' with opentype

Tags: cjk, opentype

With the help of Source Han Serif (思源宋体), one can pseudo-encode some unencoded glyphs, such as the following Chinese character:

[image]

One can do this through the use of their IDSes (Ideographic Description Sequences) and the 'ccmp' (Glyph Composition/Decomposition) GSUB feature.
The IDSes are `⿺ 辶⿳穴⿰月⿰⿲⿱幺長⿱言馬⿱幺長刂心` (traditional) and `⿺ 辶⿳穴⿰月⿰⿲⿱幺长⿱言马⿱幺长刂心` (simplified).

How can we do that in LaTeX?

(Note: the IDSes may not display normally on your computer!)

More information can be found in [Designing & Implementing Biáng](https://blogs.adobe.com/CCJKType/2017/04/designing-implementing-biang.html)
and [IDS + OpenType: Pseudo-encoding Unencoded Glyphs](https://blogs.adobe.com/CCJKType/2014/03/ids-opentype.html).

Comment: Interesting question but I have no answer. My only guess is to try using XeTeX since it supports Unicode out of the box (no need for `inputenc`, `fontenc`) and allows for the easier implementation of fonts.

Comment: You _could_ work around by designing the biáng character in Metafont and put it in via a font call where-ever necessary. I leave the details of how to do that to the font experts here. Other work-arounds: Put it as a high-resolution image where necessary (for example as .eps for proper scaling) or draw it with tikz (difficult but achievable).

Comment: Related, though it has no answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/367113/117534

Comment: TUGboat, Volume 24 (2003), No. 1 — Proceedings of the 2003 Annual Meeting, contains an article "Chinese character synthesis using METAPOST" by Yiu and Wong that attempts to develop a character building system similar to the IDS. I don't know what ever came out of that effort but maybe you can follow up on their work.

Comment: @Troy It's not related.  It is an exact duplicate.

Comment: Do you have font where your glyph is on a code point (e.g. in the private area)?

Comment: No. But what I want to do is just using the ccmp feature to make this glyph, just as the question @Troy mentioned.

Comment: @Stone-Zeng There's now an answer to the question I linked. Does that answer your question?