# LuaLaTeX not outputting ligatures in Helvetica Neue TrueType Collection

Tags: fonts, luatex, fontspec, ligatures, luaotfload

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{HelveticaNeue.ttc}[
  UprightFeatures = {FontIndex=0}
]

\begin{document}

ff fi fl ffi ffl

\end{document}
```

When I compile it using LuaLaTeX, no ligatures appear. Yet when I examine the relevant subfont in FontForge, each of the expected ligature glyphs appear at Latin Ligatures. (The only clear difference is that in `ff`, `ffi` and `ffl`, the fs are joined.)

Adding `Ligatures = Common`, `Rare`, `Historical`, `Contextual`, or `Required` results in the following error message:

```
Package fontspec Warning: OpenType feature 'Ligatures=Common' (liga) not
(fontspec)                available for font 'HelveticaNeue' with script
(fontspec)                'CustomDefault' and language 'Default'.
```

Inserting the following after `\usepackage{fontspec}` as suggested in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/315635/169189) has no effect:

```
\directlua{
  fonts.handlers.otf.addfeature{
    name = "liga",
    type = "ligature",
    data = {
      ['f_f'] = { "f", "f" },
      ['f_i'] = { "f", "i" },
      ['f_f_i'] = { "f", "f", "i" },
      ['f_l'] = { "f", "l" },
      ['f_f_l'] = { "f", "f", "l" },
    },
  }
}
```

How can I enable these ligatures in HelveticaNeue.ttc using LuaLaTeX?

Comment: do you get the ligatures with xelatex?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Yes—and all I need is `\setmainfont{Helvetica Neue}` for that.

Comment: Try with the testing version here https://github.com/zauguin/luaotfload/tree/macfonts. You need the texmf-folder, save it somewhere and activate it with `tlmgr auxtrees add path/to/the/texmf`. You probably will have to delete the font caches first, so expect that it will take some time until they are recreated. (I'm assuming that you are on a mac ...)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I did as directed, except the command I used was `tlmgr conf auxtrees add path/to/the/texmf`. I also executed `luaotfload-tool --cache=erase` to delete the font caches. Upon rebuilding the MWE, no luck.

Comment: pity, would have been too much luck. Add an issue at https://github.com/u-fischer/luaotfload/issues and look at issue #73 for the info needed to track down the problem (unless you know of a source for the font that would allow us to run the tests).