# Unable to disable ligatures for TrueType Collection in XeLaTeX

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontspec, ligatures, resume

I'm writing a resume in XeLaTeX and I'd like to disable ligatures in my document so the text is properly parsed by ATS.

I was able to disable ligatures for my OTF font but I'm having trouble with my TTC font. I have the following in my preamble:

```
\setsansfont[
    Ligatures=NoCommon,
    Path=./fonts/HelveticaNeue/,
    UprightFeatures={FontIndex=0},
    BoldFeatures={FontIndex=1},
    ItalicFeatures={FontIndex=2},
    BoldItalicFeatures={FontIndex=3}
]{HelveticaNeue.ttc}
```

However, I get the following warning:

> Package fontspec Warning: OpenType feature 'Ligatures=CommonOff' (liga) not available for font 'HelveticaNeue' with script 'CustomDefault' and language 'Default'.

When I do `{\sffamily ff}` the two Fs are very clearly connected and are a ligature. I converted the TrueType Collection to individual TTFs online and inspected some of them which showed that they *do* in fact support common ligatures. I'm essentially experiencing the opposite of [this other TeX question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/501715/lualatex-not-outputting-ligatures-in-helvetica-neue-truetype-collection). How can I forcefully disable these ligatures in XeLaTeX?

Comment: The pdf should normally contain ToUnicode mappings for the ligatures, so why should they be a problem?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer My understanding was that ATS parsers would be confused by such unicode characters when examining the PDF contents. However, I've just run my résumé (with ligatures) through pdftotext and it seems to produce the expected plaintext output. Perhaps I'm overly worried about nothing...