# How can I change the kerning between two specific letters (and thus create a ligature)?

Tags: ligatures

I am making a document using the font Minion Pro, which lacks an 'oo' ligature (ie U+A74F: ꝏ).  I would like to therefore artificially create this ligature by automatically reducing the spacing between any occurrence of the letter pair 'oo'.  I can do this manually and create a command (eg `\oo`), but that would be quite annoying compared to the ease of other ligatures.

Below is the effect I'd like, albeit cumbersomely created:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Minion Pro}

\begin{document}
    \Huge
    Bo\hspace{-.15em}ok\par Book
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: luatex or xetex (different code would be required for each)

Comment: Instead of a ligature, you could make it a macro, `\newcommand\oo{o\hspace{-.15em}o}`, thus using `B\oo k`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Preferably XeTeX as that's what my document currently uses!

Answer (score 3):

Here, I make `o` active, which you don't want in general, so I provide `\myligON` and `\myligOFF` to bound its use.

```
\documentclass{article}
\let\svO o
\newcommand\OOkern{\hspace{-.15em}}
\newcommand\myligON{\catcode`o=\active }
\newcommand\myligOFF{\catcode`o=11 }
{\catcode`o=\active \gdefo#1{\svO\ifxo#1\expandafter\OOkern\fi#1}}
\begin{document}
Book

\myligON Book hop \myligOFF
versus Book hop

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn’t do this everywhere, only for special effect in titles at display size. But the method of kerning Ulrike Fischer explains at [How to adjust font features in LuaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/312160) does the job:

```
% compile with lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\directlua{
 fonts.handlers.otf.addfeature{
   name = "oooh",
   type = "kern",
   data =
   {
     ["o"] = { ["o"] =  -175 },
   },
 }
}
\setmainfont{Minion Pro}[RawFeature=+oooh]
\begin{document}
Look at the old book in the nook.
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: Brilliant! Do you by any chance know how to do this in XeTeX?

Comment: No, sorry, XeTeX is a different animal, and I rarely use it.

Answer (score 2):

A `XeTeX` solution to complement @Therese's `LuaTeX` answer, making use of the `Interchartoks` feature:

```
\documentclass{article}
\XeTeXinterchartokenstate = 1
\newXeTeXintercharclass \mycharclasso
\XeTeXcharclass `\o \mycharclasso
% between "o" and "o":
\XeTeXinterchartoks\mycharclasso\mycharclasso={\kern-2.5pt }
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Minion Pro}
\begin{document}
    \huge\centering Look at the old book in the nook.
\end{document}
```

[image: ligatured text]

Comment: +1 sorry was working on, well work, so didn't get back to this but I see you figured it out.