# Disable “Th” ligature in LuaLaTeX

Tags: luatex, ligatures

Like *The New Yorker*, I want my Adobe Caslon Pro to have ligatures for *ffl, ffi,* etc. but not for *Th.*

Using LuaLaTeX, **how can I simply disable the *Th* ligature**? Is it possible to do this without using the `selnolig` package, and, if not, could you tell me exactly how I should alter my preamble to make `selnolig` work?

```
\documentclass[fontsize=13.5pt,oneside,DIV=calc]{scrbook}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Adobe Caslon Pro}
\usepackage[paperwidth=150mm,paperheight=225mm]{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=0.55in,bmargin=0.5in,lmargin=0.6in,rmargin=0.6in}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\MakeOuterQuote{"}
\MakeInnerQuote{´}
\automatichyphenmode=1
\frenchspacing
\usepackage{polyglossia}\setdefaultlanguage[variant=american]{english}
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

> Note: The solution in this answer gives more fine grain control to disable/enable ligatures than using selnolig. AFAIK, selnolig disables the ligature globally for all fonts. The original question doesn’t mention the intent to disable Th ligature for all fonts used in the document, on the contrary it names the exact font family “Adobe Caslon Pro” for which it should be disabled. With fontspec solution you can achieve either result: globally disable for all fonts or on a per-font basis.

This lualatex solution is from the detailed answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/312154/how-to-adjust-font-features-in-luatex). Run with command `>> lualatex <filename>.tex`. The source of this is from ConTEXt land, look at section 8.14 ["Fonts out of ConTEXt", by Hans Hagen of Pragma ADE](http://www.pragma-ade.nl/general/manuals/fonts-mkiv.pdf)

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\directlua{
  fonts.handlers.otf.addfeature{
    name = "noth",
    type = "multiple",
    data = {
      ["T_h"] = { "T", "h" },
    },
  }
}

% Option-1 To disable the ligature for just Adobe Caslon Pro
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX,RawFeature=+noth]{Adobe Caslon Pro}

% OR

% Option-2 To disable the ligature globally for all fonts
\defaultfontfeatures{RawFeature=+noth}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Adobe Caslon Pro}
```

Comment: I'm incredibly impressed you managed to work this out. I can't imagine how much learning of LaTeX I'll have to do to be able to get to this level. You have solved a problem I have spent months trying to fix. I cannot articulate how grateful I am for this seemingly tiny thing.

Comment: @Richie101 Am happy it helped you. There is a lot to learn, it just takes time, and depends on background. I don't think I have myself reached the level where I envision myself to be in TeX knowledge :)

Comment: @Richie101 I have updated the answer as the way I interpreted it, you intended to disable it just for Adobe Caslon Pro, and do not mention what should be the effect on other fonts (like whether this is intended to be a global change or not). Now you have more options, choose what works for you.

Comment: Is there a way to make something like this work with `Renderer=OpenType` ?

Answer (score 26):

You asked, among other things,

> ...could you tell me exactly how I should alter my preamble to make `selnolig`  [disable the "Th" ligature globally]?

Here you go:

```
\usepackage{selnolig} % don't specify a language option
\nolig{Th}{T|h}
```

For more information, see section 5.5 of the package's user guide, "How to use the selnolig package to suppress certain ligatures *globally*".

Comment: Is there a way to do this so that it only applies to a specific font? If I wanted selnolig to just apply to Adobe Caslon Pro, could I do that?

Comment: @Richie101 - No. That would require a *major* rewrite of the package. Incidentally, I don't quite understand the *premise* of your follow-up questions. If you want to suppress the `Th`-ligature that's provided by, say, `Adobe Caslon Pro`, why wouldn't you also want to suppress it for all other fonts that feature this particular ligature? Suppose, say, that your document features both `Adobe Caslon Pro` and `EB Garamond`. What will your readers think when they notice that the `Th`-ligature is suppressed in one font but not the other? After all, the `Th`-ligature is very easily noticed.

Comment: I might want enable ligatures for occasions where I use sans serifs for titles.

Comment: @Richie101 - Can you provide an example of a sans-serif font that provides a `Th`-iigature? (I'm not familiar with any such font, but of course that needn't mean much...) BTW, the `selnolig` package provides the `\uselig` macro, with which one can override `\nolig` rules on a case-by-case basis. E.g., `\section{\uselig{The This That There Then}}`.

Comment: Absolutely. `PTL Attention` uses a discretionary ligature for `Th`. But I don't want to necessarily just enable ligatures for `Th`. Your answer is perfect though. It is great that `selnolig` does not require a major rewrite; `\nolig` will be very useful.