# Long tailed Q with cronos pro in fontspec

Tags: fontspec

The font Cronos Pro includes a long-tailed Q glyph that I can access in the typography pane of Mac's TextEdit.  However, I cannot seem to get, despite playing with raw feature to try to trigger contextuals, the glyph to appear in Fontspec.  Is there a way to do this?
My non-working code is below; please note that I have also tried `+aalt`, but this merely messed up every letter other than the Q (which remained short-tailed).

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[RawFeature={+calt,+liga,+dlig,+hlig,+onum,+pnum,+swash},]{Cronos Pro}
\begin{document}
    Queen
\end{document}
```

Comment: I don’t have the font, but it looks as if it’s defined as a stylistic alternate (`+salt`).

Comment: @Thérèse Well, that brilliantly gets me the Q-swash (thank you !!) , but it also creates lowercase e-swash (ugh)—is there a way to activate only 1 letter's `+salt` ?

Comment: Are you using `xetex` or `luatex`? I rarely use `xetex` and don’t know much about it, but `luatex` allows you to make your own font features (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/312154 for examples).

Comment: @Thérèse `xetex` .... took me a bit to figure it out, but `interchartoks` did it.

Answer (score 2):

With thanks to @Thérèse for the tip to look at `+salt`, I solved this using XeLaTeX `interchartoks` :

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Cronos Pro}

\XeTeXinterchartokenstate = 1
\newcommand{\style}{\addfontfeature{RawFeature=+salt}}
\newXeTeXintercharclass \mydigitsclass 
\XeTeXcharclass `\Q \mydigitsclass
\XeTeXinterchartoks 0 \mydigitsclass = {\begingroup\style}
\XeTeXinterchartoks 4095 \mydigitsclass = {\begingroup\style}
\XeTeXinterchartoks \mydigitsclass 0  = {\endgroup}
\XeTeXinterchartoks \mydigitsclass 4095  = {\endgroup}

\begin{document}
Queen%
\XeTeXinterchartokenstate = 0%
Queen
\end{document}
```

[image: queen queen]