# Adding a Flourish to a Word

Tags: fonts, font-encodings, calligraphy

Consider, say, the word

[image]

which was produced by the following MWE code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pbsi}
\usepackage{scalefnt}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\scalefont{6.00}{\bsifamily{E v e r y}}
\end{document}
```

I would like to add a flourish to the letter $y$ so that the word $every$ looks something like this:

[image]

QUESTION: How may this be accomplished with the ability to modify the flourish (such as, e.g., increasing or decreasing the thickness or measure of the arc) to adapt to other fonts as well?

Thank you.

Comment: Why are you separating the letters in a cursive font? Flourishes emphasize the role of the hand, while breaking up the script’s continuity does the opposite.

Comment: It can’t look natural. The brush is moving toward the upper right as it forms the tail, and you want to add something moving lower left.

Comment: @Therese Simply speaking, I am looking for something that resembles the picture that can be adapted to any font.

Comment: you are using pdftex, if you used luatex and opentype fonts you could access the alternative swash forms that are available in some fonts, see for example the fancy Q here https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/619086/1090  note however that is part of the font design not simply a curve you have drawn underneath the word (which you could do with tikz but it won't look as integrated as a real font swash)

Comment: @David Carlisle Actually xelatex for the real case. I was not aware of what you pointed out regarding alternative swash forms and luatex. Thank you for this comment.

Comment: xelatex would work as well

Comment: @David Carlisle That's great! Thanks again.

Comment: You might try Zapfino with swashes and character variants.