# adjusting text around contextual alternate Q with lettrine in XeLaTeX?

Tags: fontspec, lettrine, swash

I'm trying to see whether there's a way I can use contextual alternate initial Q(u) in lettrine without its tail colliding with other text. Usinga fontspec's \addfontfeature{Style=Alternate} within the first set of lettrine brackets, I get the following result:

[image: image of initial Q with long tail colliding with other letters]

I'd like instead something that looks like the output example added to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/619073/contextual-alternates-and-lettrine-lualatex).

Is there a way to fix this? If I understand correctly, lettrine wasn't designed to work with contextual alternates, so I'm figuring probably not, but better to ask people who know much more than I do.

Comment: you just need (as in the referenced answer) to choose a suitable linespread don't you? As always, it would help if you provided a test document

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can raise the Q or increase linespacing, or both. An example with the freely available EB Garamond which is not such a large Q but collides in the first example but not in the next two.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec,lettrine}

\usepackage[lf]{ebgaramond}

\begin{document}


\lettrine{Q}{uaesitum}
est de Deo, Angelo et homine. De Deo quaesitum
est et quantum ad divinam naturam et quantum ad naturam humanam
assumptam. Quantum ad DIVINAM naturam quaesitum est: utrum beatus
Benedictus in visione qua vidit totum mundum, divinam essentiam
viderit.

\lettrine[lraise=.1]{Q}{uaesitum}
est de Deo, Angelo et homine. De Deo quaesitum
est et quantum ad divinam naturam et quantum ad naturam humanam
assumptam. Quantum ad DIVINAM naturam quaesitum est: utrum beatus
Benedictus in visione qua vidit totum mundum, divinam essentiam
viderit.


{\renewcommand\baselinestretch{1.1}\selectfont
\lettrine{Q}{uaesitum}
est de Deo, Angelo et homine. De Deo quaesitum
est et quantum ad divinam naturam et quantum ad naturam humanam
assumptam. Quantum ad DIVINAM naturam quaesitum est: utrum beatus
Benedictus in visione qua vidit totum mundum, divinam essentiam
viderit.

}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! Doing both (raising the Q and increasing the linespacing) solves the problem completely! It does add several pages to the document, but I'm okay with the trade-off.