# Using Variable Glyphs with fontspec

Tags: fonts, xetex, luatex, fontspec, opentype

I would like to access some alternative glyph forms using fontspec. To be specific I am using the font Garamond Premier Pro and I would like to use the alternative forms of Q (Glyph 245), W (Glyph 246) and & (Glyph 301). The font has 4 stylistic sets but using them through fontspec does not impact the shape of the letter mentioned.

Here is minimal code that still has the issue:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
    \setmainfont[Ligatures=Common, StylisticSet={1,2,3,4}]{Garamond Premier Pro}
        
\title{Title}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
Test: WQ\&.
\end{document}
```

PS: Using `Style= Alternate` in fontspec changes everything not just the three letters (it also picks an alternative form of & that I do not want).

PPS: The issue is present both with XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don’t know whether we have the same version of the fonts, because the glyph numbers you mention don’t match what I see. But in LuaTeX, you can do this (adjust the name of the ampersand glyph to `ampersand.alt2` or `ampersand.alt3` if the one shown is not the one you wanted):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\directlua{
  fonts.handlers.otf.addfeature{
    name = "malt",
    type = "alternate",
    data =
    {
      Q = "Q.alt",
      ["q.sc"] = "q.scalt",
      W = "W.alt",
      ["w.sc"] = "w.scalt",
      Wcircumflex = "Wcircumflex.alt",
      Wgrave = "Wgrave.alt",
      Wacute = "Wacute.alt",
      Wdieresis = "Wdieresis.alt",
      ["wacute.sc"] = "wacute.scalt",
      ["wcircumflex.sc"] = "wcircumflex.scalt",
      ["wdieresis.sc"] = "wdieresis.scalt",
      ["wgrave.sc"] = "wgrave.scalt",
      ampersand = "ampersand.alt1",
    },
  }
  fonts.handlers.otf.addfeature{
    name = "oops",
    type = "alternate",
    data =
    {
      ["ampersand.alt1"] = "ampersand.sc",
    },
  }
}
\setmainfont{Garamond Premier Pro}[RawFeature=+malt]% “malt” for “my alternates”; choose another name if you like
\begin{document}
Test: W Q \&.

Ẃ Ẁ Ŵ Ẅ

% because the font doesn’t have small cap ampersand variants:
{\addfontfeature{RawFeature=+oops}\textsc{Test: w q \& ẃ ẁ ŵ ẅ}}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

If you’d rather not need to remember to add `{\addfontfeature{RawFeature=+oops}...}` whenever a small caps ampersand comes into view, just invoke `fontspec` like this in your preamble:

```
\setmainfont{Garamond Premier Pro}[
  RawFeature=+malt,
  SmallCapsFeatures={RawFeature=+oops}]
```

See [How to adjust font features in LuaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/312154) for more detail. For glyphs with long tails, defining a contextual alternate is often preferable.

Comment: Thank you, this worked for me (the glyph numbers I posted are from Apple's Font Book software).

Comment: Follow up question: small caps still use the non-alternate forms of the letters, how do I fix that?

Comment: See updated answer for accented and small cap forms.

Comment: Thanks so much!