# Spacing around "ê" is too compact with Palatino Linotype

Tags: fonts, fontspec, unicode

With the font Palatino Linotype, when typing the character `ê`, the spacing around it is quite compact (see the picture below). Does this mean that I have to change my font?

(*This font was distributed by my university and I've been using it for quite a long time, so I'd really appreciate any suggestion on how to correct this behavior within LaTeX* :)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Palatino Linotype}

\begin{document}

revetement

revêtement

\end{document}
```

Comment: If using luatex, see Ulrike Fischer’s answer at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/312160. (TeX Gyre Pagella behaves better here.)

Comment: Just replace `["A"] = { ["V"] = -200 },` in [Ulrike Fischer's code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/312160/5001) with `["v"] = { ["ê"] = 190 },` if you want `vê` to be kerned the same as `ve`.

Comment: Did you try with `TeX Gyre Pagella`, which is a free Palatino clone?

Comment: @Bernard In fact in my document class `TeXGyrePagellaX` (the one used by `newpxtext`) is the backup font when `Palatino Linotype` is not found. It's just that I prefer `Palatino Linotype`, possibly due to the better sounded name :)

Answer (score 3):

Based on [Ulrike Fischer's code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/312160/194994), here is a fix for using with LuaLaTeX.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\directlua
  {
    fonts.handlers.otf.addfeature
      {
        name = "palatino-linotype-adjust",
        type = "kern",
        data =
          {
            ["r"] = { ["ê"] = 120 },
            ["v"] = { ["ê"] = 180 },
            ["w"] = { ["ê"] = 180 },
            ["y"] = { ["ê"] = 180 },
          },
      }
  }
\setmainfont{Palatino Linotype}[RawFeature=+palatino-linotype-adjust]
\setsansfont{Palatino Linotype}

\begin{document}
  rê vê wê yê (after)

  re ve we ye (comparison)

  \sffamily
  rê vê wê yê (before)
\end{document}
```