# Minor adjustment to math font kerning with unicode-math

Tags: unicode-math, kerning

I would like to use KpMath as my main math font, but also to use the letters and numbers from usual Palatino to match my main text. For this purpose, I replaced the letters and numbers from the font `texgyrepagella-math.otf`. However, in doing so, the space before the letter `f` becomes too small:

[image]

which should be like

[image]

Of course I can fix this in my document by manually add a `\,` before each letter `f`. However, it would cause a lot of trouble if one wishes to change the font afterwards. Is it possible to simply modify this spacing?

Below is a MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\setmathfont { KpMath-Regular.otf }
\setmathfont { texgyrepagella-math.otf }
  [
    range = { it / { Latin, latin }, bfit / { Latin, latin }, up / num, bfup / num }
  ]
\setmathfont { KpMath-Regular.otf } [ range = {} ]

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\( (f) \)

\( f_i f_j \)

\( 123 \)

\end{document}
```

Comment: Looks like a design choice with all the texgyre math fonts - luacode can rewrite the kerning and substitution tables, if that helps (until if/when the fonts are updated...?).

Comment: @Cicada How should one do this for a math font? The only example I've seen is [Ulrike Fischer's code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/312160/194994) for usual text font, where the character before can only be a letter; but with math font the previous content could be subscript, brackets and other types, which seems much complex.

Comment: Complex, yes. For clarity and scope, ask a separate question so more eyes are on it. `TeXbyTopic` has four chapters on math, and chapter 7 of `luatex.pdf` looks useful for lua code. Mix-and-match of fonts is basically entering font-design space, and math mode is totally different to text mode, so big topics, hence specific scope required would be helpful to get an answer.