# The key 'fontspec-opentype/FeatureFile' is unknown and is being ignored

Tags: luatex, fontspec, latex3, font-features

I recently dug up an old project and tried to compile it. Seems something has changed because it claims:

```
! LaTeX3 Error: The key 'fontspec-opentype/FeatureFile' is unknown and is
(LaTeX3)        being ignored.
```

when it is trying to set up my font in the following line:

```
\newcommand{\mysectionfont}{\fontspec[Ligatures=TeX, FeatureFile=gillsansmt.fea]{GillAltOneMT-Light.ttf}}
```

Does anyone know what I should write now in 2023 to specify a font feature file?

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/312154

Comment: Support for `FeatureFile`s has been removed from `fontspec` as of version 2.6. Use the new `fonts.handlers.otf.addfeature` function via `\directlua` instead. If you need help, please show the contents of `gillsansmt.fea`.