applying stylistic sets on parts of an arabic word (in xelatex/lualatex) causes words to split in the middle
I bought the beautiful Arabic font that supports many stylistic sets. One of these has to do with the two forms for the kaaf:

When I apply the relevant stylistic set to an entire word, it renders all the kaaf in the same style:

But if I would like the first kaaf to be in one style and the second kaaf to be in another style, I need to apply the stylistic set to part of the word. In that case, the letters do not connect properly:

Now the author of the font tells me this font works well in InDesign, but the same phenomenon happens in MS Word... I've tried to render this both in xelatex and lualatex, and both cause the word to "split", that is, to recognize the first half as a separate word. Before I despair and move on, is there anything I can do, in xelatex or lualatex, to get this "to work", namely, to be able to apply a stylistic set to a part of the word without causing the renderer "to think" that the first part "has ended"?

You need to supply more information. E.g., which OpenType features does the font have? How did you try to use them? Were you using arabluatex, arabxetex, or some other package? Etc.

I tried this both in xelatex and in lualatex:
{\addfontfeatures{RawFeature={-ss20;+ss10;+ss12;-ss13;+ss17}}كع}ك
This lets me apply stylistic sets to the text. But when I apply it to part of a word, it does not connect to the rest of the word.

Does the font define any contextual alternates? Which renderers (§VI.1 of fontspec manual) have you tried?

Yes. Many. But the particular substitutions in which I'm interested are defined only in ss10 (stylistic set). These contain one substitution that I don't want. Ideally, I would remove it and recompile the font, but alas, I purchased the font and do not have the right to modify it. When I apply ss10 just to a part of the word, the characters no longer connect, as per arabic.

I've tried to do this using Graphite and HarfBuzz.

Luatex allows you to adjust font features without editing the font: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/312154
